# How to make JsonArray clear in android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am building and android application and using pull down referees. I wanna to clear the old jsonArray data and reload the new data that coming from server.

I have tried many thinking like - JsonArray test = new JsonArray(), JsonArray test("[]");

but nothing is working can some one help me in solving this.

Comment: What you could do is pull down your json data and each time before you save them, truncate the respective table so that you have a new set of data each time;

Comment: @Eenvincible how can I do this

Answer (score 2):

Try this for clearing JSONArray:

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: try this also but did not work can you suggest something else

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a while loop across the length of the test and at each time delete the first index. the loop will reach a stage when the length of the test is zero to show the test is not empty and and cleared.

```
while (test.length() > 0) {
        test.remove(0)
}
```